# Can't connect to site using OpenSSL library

Tags: network-programming, openssl, client

I've written a simple code that illustrates basic connection. Here it is:

```cpp
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ErrorToString(int error);
char errorstring[32];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
SSL_CTX* ssl_context = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
if (ssl_context == NULL)
{
    cout << "Failed to create SSL_CTX object" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}
cout << "Created SSL Context" << endl;
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ssl_context, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ssl_context, 4);
SSL* ssl_struct = NULL;
cout << "Created SSL Struct" << endl;
char address[] = "localhost:505";                  //ADDRESS
BIO* bio_sock = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ssl_context);
if (bio_sock == NULL)
{
    cout << "Failed to create BIO" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}
cout << "Created BIO" << endl;
BIO_get_ssl(bio_sock, &ssl_struct);
if (!ssl_struct)
{
    cout << "Can't locate SSL pointer" << endl;
}
SSL_set_mode(ssl_struct, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio_sock, address);
int err = BIO_do_connect(bio_sock);
Sleep(10000); //wait while connecting
if (err != 1)
{
    cout << "Error in connecting to " << address << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}
cout << "Connected with BIO socket: " << address << endl;
err = BIO_do_handshake(bio_sock);
if (err != 1)
{
    cout << "Handshake error" << endl;
    ErrorToString(SSL_get_error(ssl_struct, err));
    cout << SSL_get_error(ssl_struct, err) << " : " << errorstring << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}
/* Step 1: verify a server certificate was presented during the negotiation */
X509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl_struct);
if (cert)
{
    X509_free(cert); //Free immidiatly
    cout << "Ok in step 1" << endl;
}
if (cert == NULL)
{
    cout << "Error. Certificate couldn't be verified.";
}

/* Step 2: verify the result of chain verification */
err = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl_struct);
if (err != X509_V_OK)
{
    cout << "Failed in step 2" << endl;
}

}
```

It creates **ssl_context, ssl struct, bio,** **it locates pointer**, but it gives me **error in connecting**
I created a simple TCP server on localhost with port 505 to try this client and server indicates that client connected, but client doesn't return 1 in **BIO_do_connect(bio_sock)**
It gives me error 5 - **SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL.** But I don't understand the reason.
I also made a loop with **BIO_do_connect**. But didn't reach any results
What's the problem here?
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out Rescorla's [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part I)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part1.pdf) and [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part II)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part2.pdf). The OpenSSL wiki also has a brief example at [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client).

Comment: *"... but it gives me error in connecting"* - you need to tell us the error.

Comment: I already checked out SSL client at OpenSSL wiki. My client has just a little bit smaller size and all I want, just to see it connects or not. All SSL details, such as creating SSL tunnel and verification, authentication and etc. I will do later.